# Routing optimization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on routing right now in order to have url easier to read on the address bar.

For example, if the basic url is: **.../Affaire/SearchAffaires?OnlyFavorite=True**

I added the route below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search Affaire Only Favorite", // Route name
    "Affaire/SearchAffaires/OnlyFavorite", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Affaire",
         action = "SearchAffaires",
         OnlyFavorite = true } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The url is now displayed like this: **.../Affaire/SearchAffaires/OnlyFavorite**

So far, so good for me.

Another example, if the basic url is: **.../Affaire/SearchAffaires?IdStatus=1**

With the following Status table:

1 = Open / 2 = Close / 3 = Cancelled

How can I obtain an url like this: **.../Affaire/SearchAffaires/Open** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class SearchRoute : Route
{
    public SearchRoute()
        : base(
            "Affaire/SearchAffaires/{searchToken}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires" }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()
        )
    { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var searchToken = rd.Values["searchToken"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchToken))
        {
            return rd;
        }

        if (string.Equals("OnlyFavorite", searchToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            rd.Values["onlyFavorite"] = true;
        }

        var statuses = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            { "open", "1" },
            { "close", "2" },
            { "cancelled", "3" },
        };

        string idStatus;
        if (statuses.TryGetValue(searchToken, out idStatus))
        {
            rd.Values["idStatus"] = idStatus;
        }

        return rd;
    }
}
```

which you would register like this:

```
routes.Add("Search Affaires", new SearchRoute());
```

Here's how this will work:

- `Affaire/SearchAffaires/OnlyFavorite` will route to the `SearchAffaires` action of the `Affaire` controller and be passed `onlyFavorite=true` argument.
- `Affaire/SearchAffaires/open` will route to the `SearchAffaires` action of the `Affaire` controller and be passed `idStatus=1` argument. Same for `close` and `cancelled`.
- Any other url patterns will be ignored by this route